# Rewrite current URL to similar URL in different folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, xampp

I'm not a very .htaccess expert, I want to redirect a URL like **"domain.com/@url"** to **"domain.com/folder/url"**, I'm triying to get the string in REQUEST_URI after the **"@"** and then use RewriteRule to add **"%{REQUEST_URI}"** after **"domain.com/folder/"**, but I have no idea how to do this

I've been searching through this issue since weeks, and I've reading a lot about .htaccess, but I can't do this still

My current code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^@.*$ /users/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: `https://example.com/@some/path` is a very strange URL pattern. Are you certainly that is what you want and not some issue you should solve _first_ ?

Comment: About doing research yourself... All those weeks that you did research, did you ever take a look into the documentation of the tool you are using? The tool is _not_ ".htaccess", that is only a configuration file. It is the apache http server's rewriting module you are interested in: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: the new url path should not have the @ on it, I think you don't get it, I've searched a lot about rewriteurl and it works just fine on Apache server, I just don't have the knowledge I need for the issue I'm facing

Comment: Rewriting does not change the pattern of the requested URL, how should it? It only takes care that that what is requested using that URL can internally be mapped onto something existing or something that can be generated. You yourself state that the "@" is part of the URL pattern you use. And below you confirmed a solution which cements exactly that. Yet here you claim different. But whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You group string after `@` into a group and pass into the output.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*@(.*)$ /users/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: If you only use the second capturing group, then why do you define two at all?

Comment: Good notice. I fixed my answer.

Comment: god bless you man, it was exactly what I was lookin for!